# Storing UserID with oAuth 2.0

Tags: oauth-2.0

I have a web app with multiple microservices (node.js)

It has an internal user base stored in a DB.

When a user wants to login with oAuth we get the username in the OpenID token and we match it with one in the db to get the userID.

Should I store the userID in a cookie so it's available to all microservices and somehow validate it with an internal token that my app will generate which will be stored also in the cookie and validate the access token separatly? Meaning 2 validations.

Or should I extract the username again from the access token, match it again with the db, get the userID and store it in the session of each microservice when it's being accessed for the first time?

I know both approaches will work, I'm asking best practice when using an in-app user base.

Answer (score 1):

The recommended approach is to create a Session ID, save that in a cookie and then create a DB entry on your server matching the Session ID to the user data.

Then, when the browser communicates with the server, the Session ID is looked up and the associated user info is fetched. You can also associate the access token with the Session ID.

[https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Session_Management_Cheat_Sheet.html#session-management-implementation:~:text=The%20meaning%20and,internal%20session%20details](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Session_Management_Cheat_Sheet.html#session-management-implementation:%7E:text=The%20meaning%20and,internal%20session%20details).

So, to answer your question. It's both and neither. You use a cookie, but to store the Session ID, not the userID. And you do match it against the db, but you're matching the Session ID with the Session Object (i.e., the object containing whatever info you've received and your app needs).

The OIDC spec also has some info about sessions if the OIDC provider supports session management. But, this is more about whether a user is logged in or not. It depends on your application and whether having a username necessarily means the user is logged in.

[https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-session-1_0.html#CreatingUpdatingSessions:~:text=In%20OpenID%20Connect,Authentication%20Error%20Response](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-session-1_0.html#CreatingUpdatingSessions:%7E:text=In%20OpenID%20Connect,Authentication%20Error%20Response).

Comment: In that case  my app is validating the Session ID token against the user ID. What would be the point of the access token then? Should I still validate it? I'm not really extracting any claims from it.

Comment: If you're not using the access token for anything, then, ya, there's no need to even request it, request the ID token and validate that. The benefit would be to not risk (directly) revealing info from the ID token if storing it client-side. Instead, you use the Access token to fetch user info.

Answer (score 0):

The best would be to have just one API gateway microservice - so your frontend  communicates only with the gateway and no other microservice deals with frontend authentication/authorization.

If you already have OAuth2 tokens, I think there is no need to introduce cookies - just send an OAuth2 token in each request to your microservice. Cookies introduce new kind of problems with security and it's not possibile to have multiple browser tabs open with different identities (they share the same cookies). And it would be hard to perform a logout (to remove all the cookies from all microservices). But you can use them if you want (with a distributed session storage).

Don't generate your own tokens - you will be creating your own security protocol, which will just have its own security problems.

Comment: Eventually I will need to cache my userID somewhere so that I won't have to match the user name from the access token against my DB on every resource access request. And if I store it in session of each microservice the session mechanism will generate a cookie with a token from the framework. So either way I end up with a cookie and a token other than the access token.